# Random matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I need to create at least 2 matrix 4x4, multiplicate them and display the result, but I'm getting this thing as as result [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko40N.png)

I'm creating matrix a[i][j] and matrix b[k][l], and trying to pass the result to a new matrix called c[i][j]
Besides that, I need to make 2 kinds of matrix multiplication, one like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOsq0.png), and another one like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Qth.png)

Can you please please please help? Code below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

int matriz1() {
    int a[4][4], i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            std::cout << a[i][j] << '\t';
        std::cout << '\n';

    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "x" << std::endl;
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "Matriz 2:" << std::endl;

    int b[4][4], k, l;
    for (k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
    {
        for (l = 0; l < 4; ++l)
        {
            b[k][l] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        }
    }

    for (k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
    {
        for (l = 0; l < 4; ++l)

            std::cout << b[k][l] << '\t';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    int c[4][4], m, n, x;
   
 
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        cout << " RESULTADO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                cout << c[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
        return 0;
    }


int main()
{

    srand(time(0));

    std::cout << "Matriz 1:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << matriz1() << std::endl;

}
```

SOLVED IN THE COMMENTS! Stop disliking my post its my first post

Comment: Please don't tag `c` when you are asking a question about C++ code.

Comment: Also please copy-paste text output into the question. Don't link to images. See [ask]. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Help with what exactly?

Comment: you need to initialize the values of `c`: `c[i][j] = 0;`, that can be done in the cycles that compute `A*B`

Comment: All in all, this boils down to explain that your code has _undefined behavior_ because of missing proper array initialization.

Comment: `std::cout << matriz1() << std::endl;`  doesn't the code always return 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common "Beginner's Problem" is writing too much code. One consequence is that there are too many places where bugs and other flaws can hide.

This is in 'C', but the only 'C++' aspect of your code is using `cout` for output. `printf()` can also be used with C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fill4x4( int a[][4] ) {
    for( int r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
        for( int c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
            a[r][c] = rand() % 100 + 1;
}

void show4x4( int a[][4] ) {
    for( int r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
        for( int c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
            printf( "%5d%c", a[r][c], "   \n"[c] );
     puts( "" );
}

int showPair( int a, int b, int pos ) {
    printf( "%2dx%-2d%c", a, b, "   \n"[pos] );
    return a * b;
}

void mult4x4( int a[][4], int b[][4], int d[][4], bool x ) {
    for( int r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
        for( int c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
            // assign (=), not accumulate (+=)
            // notice the 'exchange' of row/col access of 'b[][]'
            if( x )
                d[r][c] = showPair( a[r][c], b[r][c], c );
            else
                d[r][c] = showPair( a[r][c], b[c][r], c );
    puts( "" ); show4x4( d );
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    int a[4][4]; fill4x4( a ); show4x4( a );
    int b[4][4]; fill4x4( b ); show4x4( b );
    int d[4][4];
    mult4x4( a, b, d, true );
    mult4x4( a, b, d, false );

    return 0;
}
```

Copy, paste, compile and run this to see the (random) output.

EDIT: Pointed out by a question from the OP, here's a further compaction of one function that may-or-may-not be self-evident:

```
void mult4x4( int a[][4], int b[][4], int d[][4], bool x ) {
    for( int r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
        for( int c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
            d[r][c] = showPair( a[r][c], x?b[r][c]:b[c][r], c );
    puts( "" ); show4x4( d );
}
```

Further EDIT: A common problem for those with time to fill is mucking around, shrinking code that already works. Here's the result of some of that..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *fmt1 = "%5d%.2s";
char *fmt2 = "%2dx%-2d%.2s";
char *tail1 = "       ::";
char *tail2 = "       \n";

void show2x4x4( int a[][4], int b[][4] ) {
    for( int r = 0, c; r < 4; r++ ) {
        for( c = 0; c < 4; c++ ) printf( fmt1, a[r][c], &tail1[c+c] );
        for( c = 0; c < 4; c++ ) printf( fmt1, b[r][c], &tail2[c+c] );
    }
    puts( "" );
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));

    int r, c, v, a[4][4], b[4][4], d[4][4], e[4][4], *px, *py;

    // fill 2 4x4 arrays of random ints as if both were 1x16
    for( px = &a[0][0], py = &b[0][0], v = 0; v < 4 * 4; v++ ) {
        int num = rand();
        *px++ = num       % 100; // two digits only
        *py++ = num / 100 % 100;
    }
    show2x4x4( a, b ); // display

    // show and perform the calc of the product matrices
    for( r = 0; r < 4; r++ ) {
        for( c = 0; c < 4; c++ ) {
            printf( fmt2, a[r][c], b[r][c], &tail1[c+c] );
            d[r][c] = a[r][c] * b[r][c];
        }
        for( c = 0; c < 4; c++ ) { // note b[] swaps col & row
            printf( fmt2, a[r][c], b[c][r], &tail2[c+c] );
            e[r][c] = a[r][c] * b[c][r];
        }
    }
    puts( "" );
    show2x4x4( d, e ); // show both products

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
   29     66     71     20 :   35     88     22     22
   35     80     36     85 :   53      1     28     54
   12     14     12     71 :   95     98     92     19
   62     61     89     17 :   94     63     32     43

29x35  66x88  71x22  20x22 :29x35  66x53  71x95  20x94
35x53  80x1   36x28  85x54 :35x88  80x1   36x98  85x63
12x95  14x98  12x92  71x19 :12x22  14x28  12x92  71x32
62x94  61x63  89x32  17x43 :62x22  61x54  89x19  17x43

 1015   5808   1562    440 : 1015   3498   6745   1880
 1855     80   1008   4590 : 3080     80   3528   5355
 1140   1372   1104   1349 :  264    392   1104   2272
 5828   3843   2848    731 : 1364   3294   1691    731
```

Comment: Fe2O3 thank you so much I am almost crying

Comment: Hmm, so long I didn't use C (since K&R dialect actually). I even thought that incomplete arrays in parameter list are C++ thing.

Comment: Can you please explain the reason for the bool x in void mult4x4?

Comment: @DeborahHeinig that parameter allows the one function to serve two purposes... Notice where the `if( x )` decides to swap-or-not-swap the r/c indices of array 'b'... All the rest of the code for that function is being "re-used", not copy/pasted that would create two versions to be maintained... Cheers... `:-)`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie C'mon, now... `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`... main() is a function, too... Some would even say it is the **main** function... `:-)`

Comment: Hey, can you please explain what the function "int showPair( int a, int b, int pos )" do?

Comment: @DeborahHeinig elements of both 'a[]' and 'b[]' are passed to showPair() to be printed with the letter 'x' in between. 'c' is the column 0, 1, 2, or 3. The print is: "## x ##". The value of 'c' is used to index the 4 character array ("string") selecting one character. The first 3 are SP, so a space is printed. The 4th char is LF so a new line ends this printed line of 4 "pairs"... Then, may as well use this opportunity to multiply the 2 values and return the product to the caller... Simple, no? `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

You do this:

```
c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
```

but you never initialized `c` array, it contains random values, likely something like
0xCDCDCDCD (-842150451). Initialize it like this:

```
int c[4][4] = {}
```

You have repeated code, so consider to break it up in functions, e.g. you can initialize matrices as functions and  output one as another. THat would make  code more readable  and easier to find errors.